# Syntax Error on orderby inside concat function

Tags: mysql

Showing syntax error like

> 1064-You have error in your SQL syntax.Check the manual that corresponds to your Maria Db Server version for the right syntax use near
>   residential_no REGEXP ('^[0-9]') DESC,CAST(residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)'),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)') AS UNSIGNED

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `checking`(IN `mnth` int,IN `yr` int)
BEGIN
DECLARE cus_id text;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.cust_id) FROM ttb_customer_billing b WHERE b.month_id IN (mnth) and year_id=yr   INTO cus_id;
SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT a.*,g.assoc_name,c.ward_name,d.team_ld_name,e.volunteer_name,f.scheme_name FROM ttb_customer a left join ttb_association g on g.assoc_id=a.assoc_id
left join ttb_ward c on c.ward_id=a.ward_id left join ttb_team_lead d on d.tm_id=a.team_lead_id left join
ttb_volunteer e on e.volntr_id=a.volnt_id left join ttb_scheme f on f.scheme_id=a.scheme_id WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,"',cus_id,'") > 0 ORDER BY b.assoc_name asc,  residential_no REGEXP ('^[0-9]') DESC,CAST(residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)'),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)') AS UNSIGNED' );
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: What if you change the apostrophe in all your `REGEXP` value from `'` to `"`?

Comment: Tried that but its not showing any result @tcadidot0

Answer (score 0):

If ypu want check the index  for cus_id try not using the quote sequence (the value return from concat is already a string comma separated )

```
 WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,cus_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query if it will work:

```
CONCAT('SELECT a.*,g.assoc_name,c.ward_name,d.team_ld_name,e.volunteer_name,f.scheme_name FROM ttb_customer a left join ttb_association g on g.assoc_id=a.assoc_id
left join ttb_ward c on c.ward_id=a.ward_id left join ttb_team_lead d on d.tm_id=a.team_lead_id left join
ttb_volunteer e on e.volntr_id=a.volnt_id left join ttb_scheme f on f.scheme_id=a.scheme_id WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,"',cus_id,'") > 0 ORDER BY b.assoc_name asc,  residential_no REGEXP ("^[0-9]") DESC,CAST(residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, "(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)"),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, "(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)") AS UNSIGNED')
```

Changed the `'` to `"` in all of the `REGEXP` condition.

Edit: In reverse `"` to `'`.

```
 CONCAT("SELECT a.*,g.assoc_name,c.ward_name,d.team_ld_name,e.volunteer_name,f.scheme_name FROM ttb_customer a left join ttb_association g on g.assoc_id=a.assoc_id
left join ttb_ward c on c.ward_id=a.ward_id left join ttb_team_lead d on d.tm_id=a.team_lead_id left join
ttb_volunteer e on e.volntr_id=a.volnt_id left join ttb_scheme f on f.scheme_id=a.scheme_id WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,'",cus_id,"') > 0 ORDER BY b.assoc_name asc,  residential_no REGEXP ('^[0-9]') DESC,CAST(residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)'),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)') AS UNSIGNED")
```

Comment: Tried that but its not showing any result-no error but no result @tcadidot0

Comment: I tried changing from `REGEXP ('^[0-9]')` to `REGEXP ("^[0-9]")` in my test query on MariaDB 10.3 it does return result. Maybe our condition is not similar.

Comment: Maybe in reverse? Check my second query addition

Comment: `SELECT a.*,g.assoc_name,c.ward_name,d.team_ld_name,e.volunteer_name,f.scheme_name FROM ttb_customer a left join ttb_association g on g.assoc_id=a.assoc_id
left join ttb_ward c on c.ward_id=a.ward_id left join ttb_team_lead d on d.tm_id=a.team_lead_id left join
ttb_volunteer e on e.volntr_id=a.volnt_id left join ttb_scheme f on f.scheme_id=a.scheme_id ORDER BY b.assoc_name ASC,  residential_no REGEXP ('^[0-9]') DESC,CAST(residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)'),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(residential_no, '(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)') AS UNSIGNED` If you run this?

Comment: This query is ok but when it comes under concat its showing syntax error@tcadidot0

Comment: You mean if you run the query above directly on the server it will return result? If so, maybe you need to check your `WHERE` clause. For the `CONCAT`, you can remove this part `WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,'",cus_id,"') > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `checking`(IN `mnth` int,IN `yr` int)
BEGIN
DECLARE cus_id text;
DECLARE pat varchar(20);
DECLARE pats varchar(40);
DECLARE patss varchar(40);
SET pat ='^[0-9]';
SET pats ='(^[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]$)';
SET patss ='(^[0-9]+)|([0-9]+$)';
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.cust_id) FROM ttb__customer_billing b WHERE b.month_id IN (mnth) and year_id=yr   INTO cus_id;
SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT a.*,g.assoc_name,c.ward_name,d.team_ld_name,e.volunteer_name,f.scheme_name FROM ttb_customer a left join ttb_association g on g.assoc_id=a.assoc_id
left join ttb_ward c on c.ward_id=a.ward_id left join ttb_team_lead d on d.tm_id=a.team_lead_id left join
ttb_volunteer e on e.volntr_id=a.volnt_id left join ttb_scheme f on f.scheme_id=a.scheme_id WHERE NOT  FIND_IN_SET(a.cust_id,"',cus_id,'") > 0 ORDER BY b.assoc_name asc, a.residential_no REGEXP ("',pat,'") DESC,CAST(a.residential_no AS UNSIGNED),REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.residential_no, "',pats,'"),CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.residential_no, "',patss,'") AS UNSIGNED)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```